Laravel 8.75 doesn't convert custom rule into a message
I am using Laravel 8.75 and I want to validate fields. I have created a custom rule to validate money.
The rule looks like this:
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class FlexibalCurrencyRule implements Rule
{
    private $regex = '/^([0-9]{1,10})([\.,][0-9]{1,2})?$/';

    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        return preg_match($this->regex, $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string | array
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return "currency";
    }
}


It is very plain and simple. Then in my controllers I do the following:
$requestDto = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

$validator = Validator::make($requestDto, [
    'name' => 'required|max:100',
    'price' => ['required', new FlexibalCurrencyRule],
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    // Send response to browser
}

When I call the endpoint my validation messages contain the following:
    "price": {
        "App\\Rules\\FlexibalCurrencyRule": []
    }

As you can see Laravel doesn't call the message() function. It just prints the class name. From what I understand it should call the message() function and return 'currency' as the validation rule. How can I convert a custom rule into a string message instead of the class name being returned?

I have found the answer. I was calling the failed() function on the validator object. This returns the wrong information. You need to call messages() on the validator object to get the actual messages.
